# Problems with Google Play Services

Tags: google-play-services, samsung-galaxy-j3

I am using a Samsung J3. I suddenly have problems with Google Play Services, with the message that unfortunately, it stopped. I took the following steps:

1. In apps, I forced stop, cleared cache and restarted but didn't work
2. Then I uninstalled Google Play Services with a view to reinstalling
3. I wasn't able to reinstall from the phone itself, so I turned on the option to install from other sources and installed it from the internet
4. However, it's not in my list of apps now, even though I think it was installed.

So basically when I try to open Google Play Store, no reaction. When I try to open Play Music, YouTube, Gmail, maps etc, I get the message to update, but pressing on update just brings me back to main screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give more info on how you reinstalled it from the internet? It's possible you missed a step and that's why it's not showing up

Comment: I literally went onto Google, typed in Install Google Play Services and selected Install. Maybe it didn't actually install, I'm not sure. There were no steps, no prompts to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the correct version of Google play services.

Download the latest version of [play services info APK](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/weberdo/play-services-info/) from apkmirror. This app will tell you if you already have the right one or which one to download.

After downloading the above apk, open your file manager, (on Samsung devices it's an app called 'my files') go to local storage and open a folder called 'downloads'. There look for the apk that you have just downloaded. Press on it, and it will all of you're sure you want to download from unknown sources. Agree to that, and press 'install'

When it's finished installing, you'll find the app (play services info) among all other apps. Open it, and it will tell you what version of play services you need. The app also let's you download the right version strait from the main page of the app.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Before doing anything else, BACKUP ALL DATA that is important to you.**
2. Reset you phone to factory settings.
3. If there is no success flash the original firmware of the phone:

   If your know someone who is a geek, he can "reinstall"  Android with a tool called Odin. I don't know how this works on newer Samsung phones, but back in the days, Odin  could do such things. Check sammobile.com for the ROM appropriate for your Galaxy J3 model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you're saying that Android is basically gone on my phone? So if I didn't know someone who could do the above, I could kiss goodbye to that phone?

Comment: No, but I would Just do it because I've done such thing to many times. There is probably an easier solution. Before you do anytihng stupid back up all the media (Photos,...) that is important to you.

Comment: Good idea. I hadn't actually done that yet because other stuff is still working, like basic text, whatsapp etc, so thanks...

Comment: Also not really sure how to do 2 and 3 above, especially 3.

Comment: Don't do the 3rd one if you are not confident. The 2nd  [goes so](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGheMCuFwas)

Comment: That's great thanks. I'll give it a go after I've backed up my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First of all *go to*

> Settings --> Apps --> Installed

Then check for google play servies. If it's there proceed to Step 2.

**Step 1**

Download the google play services apk from a trusted site,

https://apkpure.com/google-play-services/com.google.android.gms

https://google-play-services.en.uptodown.com/android

and instal it. Then try weather it works.

**Step 2**

*Go to*

> Settings --> Apps -->Installed --> Google Play store --> Uninstall
>   Updates and Clear Cache

then try weather it works.

If not you will need to reset your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do:

1. Go to Settings → Apps → in the upper right corner click the menu dots → select Display/Show system apps → locate Google Play Store in the list → click on it → click on the menu up right and select Uninstall updates or similar.
2. When the app returns to the default version, scroll down to Permissions and open the one referring to changing system settings and revoke that permission

What all of this does is return the Google Play Store app to the initial system version, which stops the error from occurring, as it has to do with a bug in the latest version. What revoking the "change system settings" permission does is, it stops the Google Play Store from updating itself to the latest buggy version. It will still install and update apps, but updating itself requires a deeper system access which is revoked as referenced previously.

Rejoice, now you have a bug free phone again without rooting it or doing a factory reset. This is my original solution.