# Google Play Services is not compatible with my device

Tags: google-play-services

Everything was running smooth until I got info I need Google Play Services to run GMail, Google Play Music, GoogleMaps and so on. I try to download/install it but get the message "Google Play Services is not compatible with your device". I have a Motorola G, Android 6.0.
Thank you

Comment: Did you uninstall Google play services prior to this problem? If so, try installing it again using my answer [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/190369/241679)

Comment: Google Play Services has been unistalled as I was getting the following message when trying to reinstall it:
"Google Play Services is not compatible with your device".
It wasn't before but that's the message I get when trying to download it.

Comment: May be I have to install latest version of Android. The one installed is 6.0.

Comment: So did you try my answer there, or not?